# How to create global custom directives in Vue 3 with Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, custom-directive

I created the app with the latest Vue cli and I'm trying to register a global custom directive with no success. Can someone maybe tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import "./registerServiceWorker";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

const app = createApp(App);

app.directive("highlight", {
  beforeMount(el, binding, vnode) {
    el.style.background = binding.value;
  },
});

app
  .use(store)
  .use(router)
  .mount("#app");
```

[image: screenshot to show the issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directive `v-highlight` should have a value of type string like :

```
     <h3 v-highlight="'yellow'">highlighted using yellow</h3>
    <h3 v-highlight="'#4455ff'">highlighted using blue</h3>
```

if you provided it without `''` you would have the following error :

> [Vue warn]: Property "yellow" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

This means that your directive is looking for a data or a computed property called `yellow` which is not defined in your script.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-vuex-4-modules-in-vue-3-with-typescript-forked-pzrte?file=/src/App.vue)**

I raised this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/docs-next/issues/632) and they will fix that syntax error